# Print to Side by Side views in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, printing

I have two files in side by side view tabs in Notepad ++ (Vertically Synchronized)

is there a way to print both files on the same page so I don't lose the formatting???
[Side By Side documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhXz0.png)

Comment: If you would like to keep the formatting, you can use NppExport plugin, that can copy the  text in RTF  format or HTML format, which you can paste in Word, maintaining the syntax highlighting. Just a work around.

Comment: Thanks for your help